# Zariski open set in orthogonal grassmanian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, several-complex-variables

I am confused about the following question.

Consider $\mathbb C^4$ endowed with nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form $J:=\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\end{matrix}\right)$. Let $X:=OG(2,4)$ denote the orthogonal grassmannian of isotropic 2-planes in $\mathbb C^4$. We have a matrix representation for it by nondegenerate $2\times 4$ matrix $A:=\left(\begin{matrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}&a_{14}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}&a_{24}\end{matrix}\right)$, which satisfies $AJA^t=0.$ If $\left(\begin{matrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}\end{matrix}\right)$ is nondegenerate then we can take a zariski open set of $X$ as  $\left(\begin{matrix}1&0&a&0\\0&1&0&-a\end{matrix}\right)$.  If  $\left(\begin{matrix}a_{11}&a_{13}\\a_{21}&a_{23}\end{matrix}\right)$ is nondegenerate then we have another Zariski open set of $X$ as $\left(\begin{matrix}1&a&0&0\\0&0&1&-a\end{matrix}\right)$.
But then this two sets are disjoint, which is impossible.  I think I must make a mistake but where it is?

Comment: The sets of matrices may be disjoint, but the map from matrices to the Grassmannian is not injective.

Comment: Could you show me why?  for instance which two matrices are mapped to a same point in Grassmannian?  In my opinion the equivalence classes are taken under left multiplication, then their image in Grassmanian are different.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The orthogonal Grassmannian $OG(2,4)$ has two connected components, and the two Zariski opens you describe are in different components. The same happens to $OG(n,2n)$ for any $n$.

Comment: But how to tell which component it is in?  for example can we check the positivity of the determinants?

Comment: No (over $\mathbb{C}$ positivity makes no sense). The trick is to fix one isotropic space, say $A_0$, then the components are distinguished by the parity of the dimension of intersection with $A_0$.